# Vaadin-grid(web components ) one filter for few columns

Tags: javascript, filter, web-component, vaadin-grid

On vaadin-grid webcomponents site is example:

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
      <template class="header">
        <vaadin-grid-filter aria-label="First Name" path="name.first" value="[[_filterFirstName]]">
          <input placeholder="First Name" value="{{_filterFirstName::input}}" focus-target>
        </vaadin-grid-filter>
      </template>
      <template>[[item.name.first]]</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
```

But here I have to make one more input for every path.
Is there any possible to create one input and search on few column?

Answer (score 0):

You are required to use `dataProvider` attribute. Question has also been answered in here: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/15243361